# api not working of express app on production

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

Hello I have deployed my express backend app on nginx. When calling api through postman getting error

```
502 bad gateway
```

Things I have tried:
I have started my app using pm2 start command. Configured nginx inside nginx/conf.d/file.conf. App is running on port 7000.

My conf file looks like this -

```
server

{
        server_name api.domain.com;

        location /

{
                proxy_pass api.domain.com;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```